# How to get the output against the quarters for example "FY18 Q1" when Input is provided as "2018.1"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

There is `four quarter i.e. Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4` for each `Fiscal Year(FY)`. I want to print:

- `FY18 Q1` for input `2018.1`
- `FY18 Q2` for input `2018.2`
- `FY18 Q3` for input `2018.3`
- `FY18 Q4` for input `2018.4`

The below code works fine but looking for the better approach.

```
controller.GetFormattedQuarter = function (quarter) {
  if (quarter) {
    var newQuarter = String(quarter).replace("20", "FY");
    if (newQuarter.indexOf(".1") != -1) {
      return newQuarter.replace(".1", " Q1");
    }
    if (newQuarter.indexOf(".2") != -1) {
      return newQuarter.replace(".2", " Q2");
    }
    if (newQuarter.indexOf(".3") != -1) {
      return newQuarter.replace(".3", " Q3");
    }
    if (newQuarter.indexOf(".4") != -1) {
      return newQuarter.replace(".4", " Q4");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont see any code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the string with the wanted parts.

```js
var input = '2018.1',
    output = input.replace(/^..(..).(.)$/, 'FY$1 Q$2');
    
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

There's several ways to achieve this. One would be to use a regular expression:

```js
var arr = ['2018.1', '2018.2', '2018.3', '2018.4'];
arr.forEach(function(q) {
  var output = q.replace(/^\d{2}(\d{2})\.(\d)$/, 'FY$1 Q$2');
  console.log(output);
})
```

Or you could pull apart the string itself:

```js
var arr = ['2018.1', '2018.2', '2018.3', '2018.4'];
arr.forEach(function(input) {
  var parts = input.split('.');
  var year = parts[0].slice(-2);
  var q = parts[1];
  console.log(`FY${year} Q${q}`);
})
```

Another would be to work with the input as a number:

```js
var arr = ['2018.1', '2018.2', '2018.3', '2018.4'];
arr.forEach(function(input) {
  var year = Math.floor(input);
  var q = Math.round((input - year) * 10);

  var output = `FY${year.toString().slice(-2)} Q${q}`;
  console.log(output);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.substr` and `.split` with destruction and template literals to form your string:

```js
const GetFormattedQuarter = quater => 
  (([yr, q]) => `FY${yr.substr(-2)} Q${q}`)(quater.split('.'))
  
console.log(GetFormattedQuarter("2018.1")); // FY18 Q1
console.log(GetFormattedQuarter("2018.2")); // FY18 Q2
console.log(GetFormattedQuarter("2018.3")); // FY18 Q3
console.log(GetFormattedQuarter("2018.4")); // FY18 Q4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js' to parse and format as you wish

```js
const input = ["2018.1", "2018.2", "2018.3", "2018.4"];

input.forEach(i => console.log(moment(i, "YYYY.[q]Q").format("[FY]YY [Q]Q")));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking closely to your original code, you could easily reduce the amount of similar functionality with a for loop. 
For example

```
controller.GetFormattedQuarter = function (quarter) {
  if (!quarter) {
    return;
  }
  var newQuarter = String(quarter).replace('20', 'FY');
  for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    let quarterNum = '.' + i;
    if (newQuarter.includes(quarterNum)) {
      return newQuarter.replace(quarterNum, ' Q' + i);
    }
  }
}
```